# Does accessing webmethods keep session state live in asp.net?

Tags: streaming, asmx, session-state

I would like to keep the session in asp.net active. does this can be achieved by accessing only webmethods. And the reason is that page contains a live streaming from other sites and which can be accessed only by members.

If it isn't possible, please give me suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an attribute you can apply to enable session on webmethods/webservices.